# How is passport receiving the profile?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have implemented `passport` with `GitHub-Strategy`. Here's the [Glith](https://rightful-exclusive-carriage.glitch.me).
It works wonderfully and I'm receiving the user-profile on redirect from GitHub.

Now, I'm only trying to understand how this actually works 'under the hood'.
I did not find any similar question here on stackoverflow, neither on [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-github/).

So if I open Chrome Developer Tools during the Auth-Flow, the following seems to be going on when I click on Login with GitHub:

1. the node route `/auth/github` is called
2. node redirects to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Frightful-exclusive-carriage.glitch.me%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&client_id=ccfcc73fac8223317176`
3. the user is presented with GitHub-Login-Page
4. User types in GitHub-credentials and clicks 'Login'
5. GitHub checks the credentials
6. If valid credentials are provided, user is authenticated and GitHub redirects to the registered callback-endpoint, which is in my case: `https://rightful-exclusive-carriage.glitch.me/auth/github/callback`
7. The callback-url has a url-parameter, e.g. `?code=02337a951c242b9202fd`. It's interesting to note, that it's a GET-method and nothing else is provided.
8. On the server, the `passport.authenticate('github', ...)` method is called inside of the `/auth/github/callback`-route.
9. When the GithubStrategy is instanciated, a callback-function is passed with the signature `function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb)`. Somehow magically, the `accessToken` and `profile` are fully available here. And I don't understand how this happens.

How is passport receiving the profile?
Is `node.js` making a server-side call to GitHub? Maybe with the `?code=<id>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that is exactly what NodeJS is doing. This doesn't have anything to do with Passport.JS or Node.JS. It is the OAuth mechanism of how authorizations work.

Whenever a the Identity provider like twitter/facebook calls your `/callback` with a `?code=` query param It then hits another url and gets the AccessToken, RefreshToken and Idtoken(which is basically the user profile).

You can check out in the source code as well:

In this [strategy.js#L157](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L157) and [strategy.js#L173](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L173) of passports oauth strategy:

```
if (req.query && req.query.code) {
    ....
    self._oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(code, params,
        function(err, accessToken, refreshToken, params) {
    ....
    }
    ....
}
```

And the [oauth2.js#L177](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/blob/master/lib/oauth2.js#L177) and [oauth2.js#L190](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/blob/master/lib/oauth2.js#L190) of `node-oauth` package can see that:

```
exports.OAuth2.prototype.getOAuthAccessToken= function(code, params, callback) {
  ...
  this._request("POST", this._getAccessTokenUrl(), post_headers, post_data, null, function(error, data, response) {
    ....
  })
}
```

Bascially a POST request is being sent to the accessTokenUrl.

Comment: Small addition to clarify, quote from the GitHub's OAuth-API-Docu: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Under '2. Users are redirected back to your site by GitHub' it says that 'If the user accepts your request, GitHub redirects back to your site with a temporary code in a code parameter' and 'Exchange this code for an access token: POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', which is the accessTokenUrl.
'the response takes the following form: access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a...'